# DocuSign SOAP API Title Tab does not keep value

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign SOAP API in an ASP.NET app in C# to send some docs for e-signature. 
One of the field is the title tab. I have the following code for that. 
When testing, the tab correctly shows the title, which is picked up from the back-end DB. But when I see the completed document, the title is changed to something else. Does anyone know how can I resolve this?
When signing, if I modify the value - add and remove space - it works OK.

```
tab5 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
tab5.RecipientID = rcpt1.ID;
tab5.DocumentID = docId;
tab5.Type = DocuSignAPI.TabTypeCode.Custom;
tab5.CustomTabType = DocuSignAPI.CustomTabType.Text;
tab5.Name = "clientTitle";
tab5.CustomTabTypeSpecified = true;
tab5.Value = (dr["Rcpt_1_Role"]).ToString();
tab5.Type = DocuSignAPI.TabTypeCode.Title;
tab5.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
tab5.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = "CLIENT TITLE:";
tab5.AnchorTabItem.Unit = DocuSignAPI.UnitTypeCode.Pixels;
tab5.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = false;
tab5.AnchorTabItem.IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
tab5.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = true;
tab5.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = -10;
tab5.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 100;
```

Comment: Does this recipient already have a DocuSign user account? If so, perhaps it is honoring what the recipient has specified in their own DS account.

Comment: Yes, the user does have an account and the title was blank. So it put the title in this record in there. But is there a way I can override that with a value from the DB?

Answer (score 1):

When using certain DocuSign tab types (such as `titleTabs` or `emailTabs` for instance) the DocuSign platform will populate some of that information from the user's account if they have one.

For example, if the user has a DocuSign account where they have entered the title "CEO", then whenever you send an envelope to that exact recipient (name and email combo) and you use a `titleTab` the system will populate from their account.

I do not believe there is a way to override this, probably your best option is to just use a `textTab` instead and with that you can populate with any data from a database or wherever else you want to supply it from.